# Trouble installing RVM after system reset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

Hello so I used to have rvm installed, but I had to wipe  my system clean and start over.  I remember installing rvm being an easy install, but I am having trouble this time around.

When I run bundle install I get the following error:

```
 Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
```

And when I type

```
rvm
```

I get

```
 command not found
```

I have tried installing RVM several different ways now.  I followed the instructions here https://rvm.io most recently.

It says the install is successful, but nothing happens.  And I get the same lack of response.

Anyone know how I can get this set up properly?  I need to get back into my rails workflow!  Thanks.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 15 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'


from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

I feel like I'm missing some small thing now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the rvm installation directory to your `$PATH` variable.

`vim ~/.bashrc`

and add this line

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"`

Comment: So I did this and it got the ball rolling in the write direction, but know when I run rails server I get the following error which i edited into the end of my question

Comment: run the command `$ gem install rails` and all the missing dependencies will be installed.